# Handling JSON response dynamically for different fields of same type with retrofit in Android

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2

I am using retrofit2 with RxJava(not RxJava2) for my android project. I have an endpoint which accepts a type parameter.

```
@GET("api/v1/accounts/{account_type}")
Observable<ResponseAccountDetails> getAccountDetails(
                                         @Path("account_type") String accountType);
```

The field in the response changes based on the account type but data remains same. For example,

when `account_type = "free_account"`, the POJO is

```
public class ResponseAccountDetails implements Serializable {
@SerializedName("free_account")
@Expose
private List<Account> account = null;

public List<Account> getAccount() {
    return account;
}}
```

when `account_type = "paid_account"`, the POJO is

```
public class ResponseAccountDetails implements Serializable {
@SerializedName("paid_account")
@Expose
private List<Account> account = null;

public List<Account> getAccount() {
    return account;
}}
```

The one way, and the easier one, I know is to have different endpoints with different POJO for each type.

Is there a better and  smarter way possible? To have just one endpoint which changes the response(field basically) dynamically based on the argument(account_type) supplied.
Any other solution which is better than the one I mentioned above?

I hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use alternate names for your POJO?

```
@SerializedName(value="free_account", alternate={"paid_account"})
```

More on the GSON docs [here](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html)

Answer (score 0):

Outside the @Diego Nolde. You can also use this way

```
public class ResponseAccountDetails implements Serializable {
@SerializedName("paid_account")
@Expose
private List<Account> account1 = null;

@SerializedName("free_account")
@Expose
private List<Account> account2 = null;

public List<Account> getAccount() {
    return account1 !=null?account1 :account2;
}}
```

Comment: yeah, it occurred to me but it din't look nice when no. of types grows.